# Does domain in text data type is stored as text in a table? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, sql-domain

Because there is no `set` type in PostgreSQL I had to use `domain`. I have named a domain *gender*. It is text type. Then in users table I have created a column with that **gender type**. Now, how is stored the gender in the users table? As text or binary?

Comment: There are [enumerated types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html), sounds like that's what you're looking for. What does your domain look like?

Comment: @muistooshort, at first it had `male`and `female` but now it also includes `not applicable`. Does `enum` allow storing both `male` and `female` at same time, if it allows then it might be not that much proper. I might stick to [ISO/IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a separate transgender value(s) rather than trying to claim that someone is both male and female at the same time? There are arrays and other non-domain custom types if you need more flexibility that a single value offers. Perhaps you need to flesh out your question a bit so that we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: In almost all cases it's better to use a proper 1:n relation instead of an enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain type is based on some basic "buildin" type always. This type specifies a binary format. So if your domain is based on "text" type, then you store data as text.